# Como capturar a query string de uma requisição Restful

Tags: python, rest, querystring, uri

Preciso pegar os parâmetros passados pela URI, por exemplo:

```
http://localhost/endpoint/param1/param2/param3
if param1 == "adduser"
    id = param2
    name = param3
```

Exemplo de uma função que não funcionou: ***busco um caminho para pode pesquisar!!!***

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def post(self):
        myargs = {}
        for field in ("id","nome"):
            myargs[field] = request.form.get(field)

        print(myargs["id"].decode("utf-8"))
        print(myargs["nome"].decode("utf-8"))

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/teste')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gostaria de registrar como conseguimos superar essa dificuldade.

Desenvolvemos uma rotina em Python + Flask

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

from api import create_user, get_sso

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/users")
def users():
    data = request.args.to_dict()
    response = create_user(**data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return "OK"
    else:
        return response.content
```

Isso resolveu o problema.